# Class properties being overwritten by other instance setters

Tags: php

Pulling my hair out over some weird behaviour.

Essentially I've got a Class that constructs a GuzzleHttp\Client and a custom object of organization data, like so:

```
// Config set-up
$config = [
    'ex1' => [
        'api_key' => getenv('EX1_API_KEY'),
        'org_id'  => getenv('EX1_ORG_ID'),
    ],
    'ex2' => [
        'api_key' => getenv('EX2_API_KEY'),
        'org_id'  => getenv('EX2_ORG_ID'),
    ],
    'ex3' => [
        'api_key' => getenv('EX3_API_KEY'),
        'org_id'  => getenv('EX3_ORG_ID'),
    ],
];

// Initialize adapters
$ex1 = new Adapter($config['ex1']);
$ex2 = new Adapter($config['ex2']);
$ex3 = new Adapter($config['ex3']);
```

Which is all a-okay, until they finish their construction with `$this->org = $org`, which overwrites all of them with the same `$org`, in this line inside the constructor:

```
// Construct connected org
$org = Organization::get($this, $args['org_id']);

$this->org = $org;
```

The frustrating part in all of this is if I assign a property of that org instead of the whole thing, each item comes through unique (e.g. `$this->org = $org->name`).

I have a feeling this has to do with my `Organization` class, but I don't know where to start debugging this. Can provide more code/context on request, but the entire code-base is [on GitHub](https://github.com/arrisar/closeio-toolbox).

Answer (score 0):

I structured my abstract Resource class as a Singleton pattern. Because of this, I could not have more than one instance at a time (thus, Singleton) and as such was just changing the properties of the same instance each time.